# aerospike server can't start with unrecognized service information

Tags: database, server, installation, aerospike

I'm trying the community edition aerospike, I followed the tutorial to install the server on my ubuntu, whose version is ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I wanted to start it with the command 'sudo service aerospike start' I got nothing but "aerospike: unrecognized service"
here's the output of the install.

```
Installing tools dependencies
Installing python-argparse
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libpython2.7-stdlib is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview
  apt-offline blueman catfish espeak gigolo gnome-desktop-data gnumeric
  gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gtk-theme-config libabiword-3.0
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libgdome2-0
  libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common
  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtkmathview0c2a libgtksourceview2.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-common liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libotr5 libots0
  libsexy2 libtagc0 libtidy-0.99-0 libunique-1.0-0 libwv-1.2-4
  libxfce4ui-utils libxfcegui4-4 link-grammar-dictionaries-en menulibre
  mousepad mugshot orage parole pastebinit pidgin-otr python3-pexpect
  python3-psutil ristretto shimmer-themes thunar thunar-archive-plugin
  thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman xchat xchat-common xchat-indicator
  xfburn xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict
  xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin
  xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter
  xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-verve-plugin
  xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin
  xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-community-wallpapers xubuntu-default-settings
  xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 401 not upgraded.
Installing python-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview
  apt-offline blueman catfish espeak gigolo gnome-desktop-data gnumeric
  gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gtk-theme-config libabiword-3.0
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libgdome2-0
  libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common
  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtkmathview0c2a libgtksourceview2.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-common liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libotr5 libots0
  libsexy2 libtagc0 libtidy-0.99-0 libunique-1.0-0 libwv-1.2-4
  libxfce4ui-utils libxfcegui4-4 link-grammar-dictionaries-en menulibre
  mousepad mugshot orage parole pastebinit pidgin-otr python3-pexpect
  python3-psutil ristretto shimmer-themes thunar thunar-archive-plugin
  thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman xchat xchat-common xchat-indicator
  xfburn xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict
  xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin
  xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter
  xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-verve-plugin
  xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin
  xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-community-wallpapers xubuntu-default-settings
  xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 401 not upgraded.
Installing python-setuptools
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python-setuptools is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview
  apt-offline blueman catfish espeak gigolo gnome-desktop-data gnumeric
  gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gtk-theme-config libabiword-3.0
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libgdome2-0
  libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common
  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtkmathview0c2a libgtksourceview2.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-common liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libotr5 libots0
  libsexy2 libtagc0 libtidy-0.99-0 libunique-1.0-0 libwv-1.2-4
  libxfce4ui-utils libxfcegui4-4 link-grammar-dictionaries-en menulibre
  mousepad mugshot orage parole pastebinit pidgin-otr python3-pexpect
  python3-psutil ristretto shimmer-themes thunar thunar-archive-plugin
  thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman xchat xchat-common xchat-indicator
  xfburn xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict
  xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin
  xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter
  xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-verve-plugin
  xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin
  xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-community-wallpapers xubuntu-default-settings
  xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 401 not upgraded.
Installing pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.5.4
pip 1.5.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
Installing py-bcrypt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): py-bcrypt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
Installing tools
dpkg -i aerospike-tools-3.7.3.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb
(Reading database ... 253432 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack aerospike-tools-3.7.3.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking aerospike-tools (3.7.3) over (3.7.3) ...
Setting up aerospike-tools (3.7.3) ...
Installing /opt/aerospike
Writing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aerospike.pth
Adding python path /opt/aerospike/lib/python
```

Comment: can you re-run the installer and post output please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems **aerospike-server-community-3.7.4.ubuntu14.04.x86_64.deb** missing in latest aerospike version( aerospike-server-community-3.7.4) please check if this file is present OR you can install older version of aerospike from here:
http://www.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-server-community

Its working for me with **aerospike-server-community-3.7.3** version

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the 3.7.3 install package, and then it works.

Answer (score 1):

The correct package for 3.7.4 ubuntu14.04 is now available in the artifacts directory.